# Using Landau-Zener formula in closed system

Tags: quantum-information

I have read [arXiv:1001.3322](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.3322) and the wikipedia page of Landau-Zener formula and I have the following questions.
In a closed system of two-level system:

1. Does the Landau-Zener formula come from the Landau–Zener approximation only? What other approximation was also made in order for it not to fail?
2. Can I apply Landau-Zener formula for a particular portion of the whole quantum annealing time only, but not the whole quantum annealing process, or for negative infinity to positive infinity? Is there a bound of how small the time difference has to be taken?
3. I cannot find similar formula for the case of energy level crossing? Why does energy level crossing prohibit us from calculating such probability?

Comment: The Landau-Zener formula supposes there is no energy level crossing. Instead, there is an avoiding level, and a probability to pass from one level to the other one, the so-called Landau-Zener transition, since the Landau-Zener formula gives the probability of such a transition. So your last question is of no sense. The other two are not clear to me. What is the Landau-Zener approximation (question 1) ? Usually the Landau-Zener formula supposes quasi-adiabatic approximation, in the sense the formula gives you the probability for the transition between the two avoided crossing levels (...)

Comment: (...) when parameters are slowly varying. In the pure adiabatic case, there would be no transition at all (the adiabatic approximation falls down close to the crossing of levels). Question 2 should be clarified too : Landau-Zener process (one more time, the possibility for a quantum state to tunnel between two avoided crossing energy levels) is far more general than quantum annealing.